# How do you stretch a div element to the footer?

Tags: html, css

My goal was to get the footer to stay at the bottom of the page and to go further down when more content is added. In doing so, a div element on my page which follows the footer has stopped half way when there isn't enough content.

My question is, how do you get the `middle-strip`div to stretch to the footer and have the goal above still achievable.

Here is a simplified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzwgdv68/14/) to show the issue.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#header {
  background: #283343;
  height: 50px;
}

#middle-strip {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  background: #32cd32;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

#content-area {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

#footer {
  background: #283343;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">
    THIS IS THE HEADER
  </div>
  <div id="middle-strip">
    <div id="content-area">
      THIS IS WHERE THE CONTENT WILL GO
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    THIS IS THE FOOTER
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox to achieve this:

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#middle-strip {
  flex: 1;
}
```

https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/